# Adding a primary key column to an existing table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to add a new column and make it the primary key in SQL Server; the table in question does not yet have a unique key column.

Here is the sample table http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8a161/1/0

My goal is simply to have a column `ID` and insert values from 1 to 1160 (total number of records in this table) and make that the primary key. Also is there a way to automatically add the numbers from 1-1160 without adding each record one by one since there are 1000+ rows in this table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply alter the table and add the column with the appropriate characteristics.

```
alter table x add id smallint identity(1,1) not null primary key;
```

Thrown together quickly and you probably should get in the habit of naming constraints. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92988196e70fe3b4a81da1a345f914c2). I will note that you may or may not want to use an identity column - think carefully about your actual goal and how you want to continue using this table after the alteration.

Comment: Thank you very much @SMor it worked perfectly. Quick question tho, if I someone try to update the current id with some existing id number will the SQL Server allow to do it? Another words, will the SQL Server allow to have duplicates in this 'id' column? I don't think since it's the primary key column but just making sure. Thanks!